# Hide ACF fields when one of them are empty

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

i use the following code with custom fields:

But the problem is; when did not put any content in one of custom field it need be hide. 
the class style of the other effect it, and that is something I don’t want to show.

```
<div class = "class2">
<? php the_sub_field ('filed2'); ?>
</div>
<div class = "class1">
<? php the_sub_field ('filed1'); ?>
</div>
```

I want hide one of both custom filed when on of them is empty.

How can i hide it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if (get_sub_field ('filed2') || get_sub_field('filed1'));{ ?>
   <div class = "class2">
    <? php the_sub_field ('filed2'); ?>
  </div>
  <div class = "class1">
    <? php the_sub_field ('filed1'); ?>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```

You would want to wrap it in an `if` statement.

You can also do (if you need the conditional logic on a per-field basis):

```
 <?php if (get_sub_field ('filed2'));{ ?>
      <div class = "class2">
        <? php the_sub_field ('filed2'); ?>
     </div>
 <?php }; if (get_sub_field ('filed1'));{ ?>
      <div class = "class1">
        <? php the_sub_field ('filed1'); ?>
      </div>
<?php }; ?>
```